# Is Roland's 'Barrage' skill worth investing in?

Tags: borderlands

Roland (the Soldier class), has the ability to deploy a Scorpio turret. One of his skills aimed at improving the turret is called *Barrage*, which:

> Increases the number of shots your Scorpio Turret fires in each burst. +1 Shots fired per burst

You can invest 5 skill points into this skill (i.e to a maximum of +5 shots fired per burst). The delay between each burst is about 3 seconds. The Scorpio Turret despawns after a certain amount of time which never varies. I believe that the default number of shots fired per burst is 3.

How effective is Barrage, objectively speaking? Does it double the turret's offensive capability? Does it actually detract from it, such as if the Scorpio Turret cannot switch targets per burst, and each burst usually kills a target in less than 4 shots? That's just an example; I know that the Scorpio Turret switches targets as soon as the one that it's aiming at dies, regardless of whether or not it's in the middle of burst fire.

Comment: Related: [In what order should I put my skill points if I want to maximize the damage that Roland's Scorpio Turret inflicts?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121369/4797)

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely worth it, since the 3 second cooldown is from the beginning of the shot, it makes the turret fire twice as much bullets.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I tested this claim and it is untrue. The cool-down in between bursts is the same. It starts from the last shot fired in a burst.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7PH9pkItjM Here's the video evidence that I've finished uploading and editing.