# In what order should I put my skill points if I want to maximize the damage that Roland's Scorpio Turret inflicts?

Tags: borderlands

I've just maxed the [Refire](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Refire) and [Deploy](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Deploy) skills of the Soldier / Roland to maximize the reduction of the cooldown of the [Scorpio Turret](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpio_Turret) skill. I am now thinking of increasing the damage of the Scorpio Turret.

[image: screenshot]

It seems that I have three skills (from the Infantry and Support skill trees) to choose from if I want to increase the damage of the Scorpio Turret: [Sentry](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry_%28Roland%29) (*increases Scorpio Turret damage*), [Guided Missile](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Guided_Missile) (*Scorpio Turret launches guided missiles in addition to using its regular gun*) and [Barrage](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Barrage) (*increases the number of shots the Scorpio Turret fires in each burst*).

**In what order should I put the next skill points that I get to maximize the damage that the Scorpio Turret inflicts?**

Also, what if I have an [Artifact](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Artifact) that adds elemental damage to the Scorpio Turret? I currently have an Explosive-bolt Artifact equipped.

Comment: The order doesn't matter, only the values. As far as I'm concerned, my [*plan*](http://talent.87bazillion.com/soldier.php?550550550530555050055) for my soldier doesn't even have maxed barrage :-)

Comment: @ChristianStieber I asked for the order because I'm currently not of a high enough level to spend points on all of those skills. This is so I'd know of the optimal skill point allocation as I level up. About your build, are you implying that Barrage doesn't give a significant boost to the Scorpio Turret's damage? Should I focus on Sentry or Guided Missile first?

Comment: As I said, that's just a plan (and, not an answer :-)) There's a limit on skill points so something has to draw the short straw; the [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Barrage) only indicates that level 6 and 9 are "bad". As for ordering, I'd start with Sentry -- according to the wiki, Guided Missle has low "return on investment". Maybe throw in a point on Barrage occasionally; it's not like the game requires you to max skills before investing points elsewhere :-)

Comment: While the question may still matter to you, I recommend that you start with Sentry, then go Guided Missile, then Barrage. Guided Missile strikes are few and far between. Barrage...well, you know my video. In terms of artifact, I'd go with fire default.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say max out both Impact and Sentry in the Infantry (blue) section of Roland's Scorpio Turret skill tree to 5/5 and invest just enough more points in the Infantry section to unlock the Guided Missile skill, which as the title suggests, causes the Scorpio Turret to deploy an occasional guided missile vs. enemies. I would advise also maxing this to 5/5 if you want to prioritize maximum damage output.